# Check selection inside or outside of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following lines of script to get selected area of a document.

```
    sel = window.getSelection();
    console.log(sel);
```

I have get the results in console as like the image below.

[image]

**My question is,**

**Is it possible to check the selected text inside or outside of a element with a specific class/id?**

Comment: I'm not following what you mean "inside or outside of a class"

Comment: @Retsam To check it is inside a div with a class /id

Comment: If i select a word from my webpage,I need to check the selection inside or outside of an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the anchorNode (the node in which the selection begins) and the focusNode (the node in which the selection ends) to try to determine whether or not the selection is in the desired element.

Assuming the element you're interested is the direct parent of the text being selected, you can do:

```
var sel = document.getSelection();
var startsInTarget = sel.anchorNode.parentElement.classList.contains("target");
var endsInTarget = sel.focusNode.parentElement.classList.contains("target");
if(startsInTarget && endsInTarget) {
     //selection is within an element with class "target"
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Retsam19/vkmcxohm/) demonstrating this idea